# How to input 2 or 4 equations as a equation system and use it as a variable in C#? Maybe could convert from MATLAB?

Tags: c#, matlab, function, equation

so I came upon an issue. I have not programmed in C# much, so I don't know how could I input 2 or 4 equations as a equation system, which I could use in my program as a variable for solving the equations? I know how to write it in MATLAB, but have no idea how to do the same in C#. Any help is highly appreciated.

Equation systems which I need to include in my C# program :
[Picture of both equation systems that I need to include](http://prntscr.com/lm8nbi)

That's how I input a system of 4 equations in MATLAB :

```
function F=f(X) 
F(1)=X(1)+2*X(2)+X(3)+4*X(4)-20.7;
F(2)=X(1)^2+2*X(1)*X(2)+X(4)^3-15.88;
F(3)=X(1)^3+X(3)^2+X(4)-21.218;
F(4)=3*X(2)+X(3)*X(4)-7.9;
F=F(:);
return
end
```

And that's how I input a system of 2 equations in another MATLAB project :

```
    function fff=f(x)
fff=[x(1)^2+x(2)^2-2;
     x(1)^2-x(2)^2];
return
end
```

I did a similar task before in C#, but the equation system ([picture of the equation system used for this case](http://prntscr.com/lm8sk5)) was very simple, so I just had to save the coefficients which were near all x values (x1, x2, x3, x4) :

```
double[,] A0 = { { 4, 3, -1, 1 }, { 3, 9, -2, -2 }, { -1, -2, 11, -1 }, { 1, 
-2, -1, 5 } };
Matrix<double> A = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(A0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)

```
namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public class Function
    {
        public delegate int X(int param);

        public static double Operation(X x)
        {
            var F1 = x(1) + 2 * x(2) + x(3) + 4 * x(4) - 20.7;
            var F2 = x(1)  + 2 * x(1) * x(2) + x(4) - 15.88;
            var F3 = x(1) + x(3) + x(4) - 21.218;
            var F4 = 3 * x(2) + x(3) * x(4) - 7.9;

            return F1 + F2 + F3 + F4;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // We give the Something function defined below to the Operation method
            // which has the same parameters as X, .
            Console.WriteLine(Function.Operation(Something));
        }

        public static int Something(int param)
        {
            return param + param;
        }
    }
}
```

The method Operation accepts a function as long as it has the same entry parameters and same return type.